# C# Deleting a .ZIP file after unzipping

Tags: c#, zip, unzip, delete-file

I am using the Ionic.Zip.dll from the DotNetZip library and I'm trying to delete the ZIP file after it finishes unzipping, but I can't manage to do it.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(nextVersion + ".zip"))
{
    zip.ExtractAll(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);

    try
    {
        File.Delete(nextVersion + ".zip");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not delete ZIP!");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try deleting the file outside your using statement. There may still be a lock on the file.

Comment: Is the ZIP file still in use?  Should you close the file before trying to delete?

Comment: Im Useing the same Dll and am also trying to Delete, Where did you get 'File' From?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting the exception because the file is still open when you try to delete.  Move the `File.Delete` to after the `using` block.

Answer (score 4):

Try this?

```
try {
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(nextVersion + ".zip"))
    {
        zip.ExtractAll(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
    File.Delete(nextVersion + ".zip");
}
catch (Exception) {
   MessageBox.Show("Could not delete ZIP!");
   Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes! I have the same answer as Richard Schneider. The zip file is still accessed by current thread, you have to close it first.

Try this

```
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(nextVersion + ".zip"))
            {
                zip.ExtractAll(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                zip.Dispose();
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(nextVersion + ".zip");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not delete ZIP!");
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move File.Delete outside using brackets using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(nextVersion + ".zip"))